# Bed frame legs don't touch floor

Tags: bedroom, frame

I got a bed frame from someone and after assembling it, the wooden legs in the middle of the slats don't touch the floor. They touch the floor only if I press down hard on the bed. Is this supposed to be the case or should I put a book between the legs and floor?

There is about 1cm of space.

[image: About 1cm of space]

Comment: How many middle legs are there? (A diagram of the leg position might help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The center post do normally touch this supports the slats and keeps the frame level. It is difficult to tell how far off the floor this is there could have been a plastic foot at one time. I would use something solid like an old phone book if you can find one, or a piece of wood.

Comment: +1 for mentioning a missing slide/plastic foot. I would add to check for a threaded insert. Some of these have adjustable feet almost like a stove, fridge, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Centre rail feet are not supposed to touch the floor. If they do, they interfere with the flex of the slats. They’re only there to prevent the slats breaking when folks initially get into bed - or jump on the bed. Or...

Generally, they should be a centimetre or so off the floor. 
Most centre rail breakages occur when people adjust the centre rail feet to TOUCH the floor. These legs don’t have much sideways strength and if they’re in contact with the floor (carpet especially) when the bed is moved sideways for cleaning, they drag on the floor and rip away from the centre rail. I’ve had to fix MANY of these things! 
(I install beds for a national bed maker).

[image: Correct centre-leg clearance]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Great answer, but is this always true, or do some types of bed frame have a support which always rests on the floor?